# else if statement does not run, even when the requirements for it are met?

Tags: javascript

```
function illegal_chr(input) {
//checks 'entry_box' for illegal characters
document.getElementById("binary_p").innerHTML = "Convert binary to text or text to binary."
var entry_value = document.getElementById("entry_box").value;
var entry_length = entry_value.length
var CHARACTERS_ARRAY = []
var illegal_message_bin = "Please ensure you have only used binary."
var ILLEGAL_BIN = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "[", "]", "#", "'", ";", ",", ".", "`", "¬", "?", ">", "<", "~", "@", ":", "}", "{", "|", "/", "!", "£", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "=", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

//adds each character to 'CHARACTERS_ARRAY'
for (var c = 0; c < entry_length; c += 1) {
    character = entry_value[c];

    CHARACTERS_ARRAY.push(character)
}

//loops through 'CHARACTERS_ARRAY' checking for any illegal characters
for (var ch = 0; ch < CHARACTERS_ARRAY.length; ch += 1) {
    characters = CHARACTERS_ARRAY[ch];

    for (var ill = 0; ill < ILLEGAL_BIN.length; ill += 1) {
        letters = ILLEGAL_BIN[ill]

        if (characters == letters) {
            document.getElementById("binary_p").innerHTML = illegal_message_bin;
        }

        else if (characters != letters && ch == entry_length) {
            alert("test")
        }
    }
}
}
```

The function checks to see if the user has used any 'illegal characters', and that works but when it contains no 'illegal' characters nothing happens?

Comment: Just a hint: in javascript the operator of equality is `===` not `==`.

Comment: Might I suggest a regex instead?

Comment: `if (characters != letters && ch == entry_length)` always `false` because `ch` can't be equal `entry_length` inside loop

Comment: even without 'ch == entry_lengtgh' nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads-up, you can use regex for that as @duffymo stated:

```
function isHex(str) {
    return str.match(/^[a-f0-9]{6}$/i) !== null;
}
```

This checks for binary number (at least one 0 or 1):

```
function isBin(str) {
    return str.match(/^[0,1].*$/) !== null;
}
```

Comment: There's more to his character array than what you have here, but it's a start.

Comment: This actually checks for 6 digits, for anything more you need to change {6} to appropriate number, or change it to *

Comment: Not the number of digits: look at the values in the illegal character array.

Comment: Added isBinary function, lol I was working on something else and concluded that he needed the hex number checking :)

Answer (score 1):

Use === and !== for comparisons.

My guess is that you're assuming that the condition is met, but JavaScript is telling you it's not.  Check your assumptions.

Wouldn't this be a one-line trivial problem with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)?

Comment: still dosn't work, if an 'illegal character' is found it works, but when there isn't a 'illegal character' nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(conditionA){
//do something
}
else if(conditionB){
//do something else
}
```

this is roughly equivalent to

```
if(conditionA){
//do something
}
**if(!conditionA && conditionB)**{
//do something else
}
```

in your "else if conditional" here it automatically means that the condition "characters != letters" is satisfied.

```
else if (characters != letters && ch == entry_length)
```

could be therefore written as

```
else if (ch == entry_length)
```

in each iteration of the for loop, ch refers to each element of CHARACTERS_ARRAY. suppose

- you had entered the text *abc* in your entry_box input element
- that would mean that the variable entry_value contains the string "abc"
- and entry_length contains 3 [the length of the text you had entered]
- and proceeding further with your code, CHARACTERS_ARRAY contains the array ['a', 'b', 'c']
- and CHARACTERS_ARRAY.length is also 3

---

for loop begins
 - for loop iteration 1: ch contains 0
 - for loop iteration 2: ch contains 1
 - for loop iteration 3: ch contains 2
for loop ends

entry_length which is 3, thus never equals a changing ch & you never see the alert.

as duffymo suggested, this would be quite straightforward to do using a regex!

Comment: thank you, but even without 'ch == entry_lengtgh' nothing happens